# vnc4server - what X server

Tags: debian, vnc, x-server, vncserver

I need VNC access for server that is already running SSH. I need to set up vnc4server. My question is what is the best X server in terms of using least resources and being fastest, what packages should I install? I am working with debian lenny.

Comment: I assume you mean "desktop environment" instead.  Almost all the distributions use Xorg.

Comment: There are VNC and RDP daemons that don't *need* a X server.

Comment: @grawity which are those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stick with Xorg (`aptitude install xserver-xorg`). Personally I don't know any other modern and usable X server implementation on Linux other than Xorg. Feel free to show me other variants though.

However, do you have to use VNC? Have you tried X forwarding ? I find X forwarding is easier to use / setup than VNC (assume your local computer runs linux) and you don't have to install the whole desktop environment on your server.

NX would top both VNC and X forwarding in term of speed and responsiveness. But a lot harder to setup (I used [NeatX](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/), not the original NX server)